# How to install and use additional voices in SpeechSynthesizer()?

Tags: .net, text-to-speech, speech

I need to use male voice in SpeechSynthesizer in addition to default Anna voice. I installed some files from Microsoft, and GetInstalledVoices() method says now I have Microsoft Anna, Microsoft Mary, Microsoft Mike and Sample TTS Voice.
After I'm trying to set voice

```
speaker.SelectVoice("Microsoft Mike");
```

my program throws exception: Cannot set voice. No matching voice is installed or the voice was disabled.

What should I exactly install and how to enable Mike's voice? System is Windows7.

Comment: When you call `GetInstalledVoices()`, is `enabled` set to `true` on the `Microsoft Mike` `InstalledVoice`?

Comment: You cannot just arbitrarily copy voices.  Mike and Mary are an old retired couple, they cannot work on modern Windows versions.  You have to go shopping, nobody creates voices for free.

Comment: @Stone yes, .Enabled is True for all 4 voices I have

Comment: @HansPassant. But why they appeared in GetInstalledVoices if they are retired? Also I downloaded Helen and ZiraPro from this link http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27224 But can't install them, installation just closes on gathering inforamtion... Where to shop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After trying many suggestions from web found working solution:

- install Microsoft Speech Platform SDK (x64) v11.0.

- install Runtime Languages (Version 11) you need.

- do registry changes from the end of this [this thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/c7409091-087e-48f2-8178-bcd918799054/add-tts-voice-to-windows-7-and-set-as-default?forum=w7itproinstall).

- install Microsoft Server Speech Platform Runtime (x64) (! - this is what i was missing).

- and you have to set platform target in build to x64 to use new voices like Helen or ZiraPro

Comment: and you have to set platform target in build to x64 to use new voices like Helen or ZiraPro

Comment: Unfortunately, MS removed version 11 from their website!    the only SDK version available is 10.2 (from 2009).  I suppose they don't support it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a lot of additional voices from Cepstral:
http://www.cepstral.com/en/personal/download

It appears that available voices are the same as CereProc has on offer: https://www.cereproc.com/en/storesapi.

When you download their software you get selected voice registered in Windows, so you can use it with `SpeechSynthesizer`.