# can't change voice in speech synth

Tags: c#, voice

I can't change voice to male. It is always default, no matter what I try. Yet in my system, there ARE male voices.

I have tried:

```
synth.SelectVoiceByHints(VoiceGender.Male);
synth.SpeakAsync("Hello, my name is Evus.");
```

- This doesn't even do anything, it will just speak with the default Cortana voice.

  foreach (var v in synth.GetInstalledVoices().Select(v => v.VoiceInfo))
  {
      Console.WriteLine("Name:{0}, Gender:{1}, Age:{2}",
                        v.Description, v.Gender, v.Age);
  }
- returns 2 male voices from my system. And yet, when I select Male it doesn't work.

I have tried to select the gender of the voices.

- That doesn't do anything either.

[How to install and use additional voices in SpeechSynthesizer()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31924110/how-to-install-and-use-additional-voices-in-speechsynthesizer)

- I tried following the answer in here, but that doesn't help either.

Comment: Using `GetInstalledVoices()`, also check the `.Enabled` property. Then try to select it by name with the [`SelectVoice()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.selectvoice(v=vs.110).aspx) method (case sensitive).

Comment: I did manage to get uilder.StartVoice("Microsoft David Desktop");, but I need Microsoft George, and that one it seems not to be able to find. How is that possible, since I have it all good in my Narrator settings.

Comment: You can't use voices that are only part of the Runtime. Anyway, for more options, see [Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.speechsynthesis) and [Microsoft Speech Platform SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh362873(v=office.14).aspx). The SDK (Namespace `Microsoft.Speech`) has some useful tools for developers and also allows you to download and use a number of voices both for speech recognition and TTS. You can reference all Namespaces, but each one has it's own voices. Also, you have to compile for a specific platform (x86 or x64).

Answer (score -1):

try to use

synth.SelectVoiceByHints(VoiceGender.Female); or synth.SelectVoiceByHints(VoiceGender.Male);

then just use synth.Speak("example");
I have had no issue switching at all